# How can I reload tableview in viewDidLoad using delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have simply TODO list in which there are:

- protocol's method `reloadTableViewWhenItChanges`;
- fetch data (i.e. core data);

Table view reloads after stop/run compiler.
But I need to reload table view in `viewDidLoad` (not in `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear`), using delegation table reloads only after something has changed in `managedObjectContext`.

How can I do that?

Here is my code (what is wrong in it? Where do I have to put `[self.tableView reloadData]` in my code, for example?):

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.title = @"Note List";
     self.barButtonAddNote = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                           target:self
                                                                           action:@selector(addNewNote:)];
     [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:self.barButtonAddNote animated:YES];
     [self reloadTableViewWhenItChanges]; }

 - (void)reloadTableViewWhenItChanges // protocol's method {
     self.addNoteViewController.delegate = self;
     if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges])
     {
         NSError *error;
         [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
     }
     [self fetchData];
     [self.tableView reloadData]; }

 - (void)fetchData {
     NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
     NSEntityDescription *note = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Note"
 inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
     [request setEntity:note];

     NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"task" ascending:YES];
     NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
     [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

     NSError *error = nil;
     NSArray *mutableFetchResults = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

     if (mutableFetchResults != nil){
         self.notesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:mutableFetchResults];
     } }
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood something.When your View Controller first load, your tableView will automatically reload using the data you provide for the first time.

But let's say you want to update tableView later.In that case you have to call reloadData function somewhere in your code.And your viewDidLoad method will never called again automatically until you change your View controller.

Comment: in `–viewDidLoad` you cannot reload a single thing for your table-view, because the view will be rendered after the view has gone into the navigation stack, like e.g. `–viewWillAppear:` or so.

Comment: Consider using `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @eik_cloner, you don't need to reload table view in `viewDidLoad` because it's done automatically.
If you want to do it manually then you have to call `reloadData` method of `UITableView` wherever you want as:

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

In Objective C :-

```
[tableViewName reloadData];
```

In Swift :-

```
tableViewName.reloadData()
```

Make sure you have Configure the delegates with UIViewController through UIStoryboard or By code.